# Can't combine two strings togetger

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

When I was doing some tricks with strings,I can't combine the string `word[0]` with word. I thought this is because they are from the same string. If so, what can I do?

```
def pig_it(text):
    l1 = text.split(' ')
    l2 =[]
    for word in l1:
        first_letter = word[0]
        new = word + first_letter +'ay'
        new = new.replace(new[0], '')
        l2.append(new)
    return ' '.join(l2)

print pig_it(('my name is frankling'))
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code on my computer and ran the file. It works fine! The first letter of each word is gone and 'ay' is added to the word.

Comment: No expected and observed results, no error message?

Comment: `new.replace(new[0], '')` - we see that mistake a lot around here. You were probably expecting that to delete only the first character, right? `replace` doesn't see "the first character of `new`" there; it sees `"m"`, or `"i"`, or whatever, and replaces all `"m"`s or `"i"`s or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem.

Comment: And I it worded correctly after changing the code into `new.replace(new[0], '',1)`,thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Its a little unclear about what you want to achieve with the above code but I rand it anyways and the code works according to the logic you have written the code

My out put was:

yay ameay say ranklingay

In case you want to do some thing specific, update the question and make it a little clear then probably i can help better.